# Not able to connect to mssql server from spring application

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, maven, jdbc

I have a spring application that connects to MS SQL Server,
I have the following dependencies added to my pom.xml,

```
<!-- ms sqlserver dependency -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jdbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

and have the following db parameters for the datasource,

```
username: uname
password: pwd
url: jdbc:sqlserver://sample.pewtest.com;databaseName=CommonTest.TestDB
driver: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

The application runs fine on my local environment using intellij. But when I build the testApp.war and deploy the application on my tomcat, I get the following exception,

**Error occurred at fetch all samples org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for  jdbc:sqlserver://sample.pewtest.com;databaseName=CommonTest.TestDB**

Any help on this greatly appreciated!

Comment: make sure that your sqlserver jar is on your classpath

Comment: are you setting the database name ? is that possible that the name contain a (dot) `CommonTest.TestDB` ?

Comment: It is actually a view that I'm querying

Comment: How is your `DataSource` setup?

Comment: I have a bean in my spring configuration, that handles this

Comment: That is quite obvious... Please add it to your question....

Answer (score -1):

i have some suggestions for you

please check whether you added SQLServer Driver "Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");" 
then check whether the jar file exisits in "maven dependency library". also check the version of jar file or try to upgrade it.

Comment: Can we please stop using `Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");` to "load jdbc drivers" that isn't needed anymore... JDBC4 drivers register themselves... Doing it like this might even introduce classloading/casting issues.